# in Iphone safari browser, getting error message while loading javascript whcih contains href

Tags: javascript, html, mobile-safari

in IPhone safari browser, i am loading html page which contains href.ie,

```
function getxxxx(link) {
            var call1 = document.getElementById('CALL1');
            if (call1 && call1.innerHTML) {
                  link.href = "tel:" + call1.innerHTML;
                  alert(link.href);
                  return true;
            }
            return false;
      }
```

I’m invoking the script like this,

```
<tr>
      <td><a class="statuscontent" href="#"
                        onclick="getxxxx(this)">
            <div class="imageContainer1">Call</div>
      </a></td>
      <td>
            <div id="CALL1" class="statuscontent"><%=custCareNumber1%></div>
      </td>
</tr>
```

while loading this page in I Phone safari browser,getting the error "ahref"tel+188828600000">+188828600000".
In other browsers or other phones like android are working fine.

Answer (score 0):

Try `call1.text` instead of innerHTML

Comment: getting tel:undefined while using call1.text instead of innerHTML.